# Content-Encoding missing in browser mob proxy request header

Tags: java, automation, browsermob-proxy

I need to fetch and verify the Content-Encoding from request headers using Browser Mob Proxy - https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy

I can collect all the requests from device. But unfortunately the Content-Encoding header is missing in the request header. How can I get this header value?

**Response Headers:**

```
Content-Type | text/plain
Date | Thu, 25 Jan 2018 04:55:14 GMT
Server | fasthttp
Connection | keep-alive
```

**Request Headers**

```
User-Agent | Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.0.0; en-us; Pixel Build/OPR3.170623.008) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
Content-Type | application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept | application/json
Host | hostname
Connection | Keep-Alive
Accept-Encoding | gzip
Content-Length | 640
```

Comment: I heard that the **content-encoding** is present in request header, when it's collected from **browser**. But has not been present in the requests collected from the **mobile app**.

https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy/issues/728

Any help would be appreciated.